# How to keep track of UPDATE and INSERT in a table SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to discuss a problem related to SQL server. I have a table called as data table. I want to save a value (time stamp) in this table. Now, this is a single value i.e 7/25/2011 7:32:41 but it will be repeated equivalent to number of rows in table. Is there any method through which I can save this value in any stored procedure provided that the stored procedure is associated with table too?

Comment: Your question is a little hard to understand. Can you give an example of the table and the data in it right how, and the data you would like to see?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I'm understanding your question, you want each row in the table to be timestamped as it is is inserted/updated, whichever stored procedure does it?

In that case, you could put insert and update triggers on the table, which can insert/update the timestamp column with the current date whenever a stored procedure touches the table..